# Adding standard deviation bars in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Excel 2007 I am using a double bar graph (like a regular bar graph, but with two columns under one x-axis value) as my chart. I have 8 x-axis values, making a total of 16 actual bars.

I need to add a different value of standard deviation for each bar (meaning 16 different values of standard deviation).

1. How can I do this?
2. How do I add the standard deviation for each bar if each standard deviation is different / unique for each bar?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Error Bars [image: Error Bars]